# What layout elements to use for following type of layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am certainly newbie to `Andorid Development`, and have a knowledge of basic stuff, `Relative Layout`, `Linear Layout`, `Intent`, `File Handling` etc....

I need to build a project similar to some `E-commerce app`.
Here's an image of what I want.
[image: Andooid Layout]

How do I achieve the given view of products, as like in blogs or other websites.
Do I have to use `List View`?

And Please tell what do I have to use to make that "`Add Filter Tags`" section and how to achieve what I have shown in the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ListView would be the "default" way. I would also have a look at RecyclerView (a newer incarnation of the same idea). It handles scrolling and recycling the list elements as you scroll, which are all things you don't really want to do on your own.

You'll probably have a separate layout for the individual cards, probably mostly LinearLayouts (horizontal for image -> content, and then a vertical one to hold the content, and maybe a third horizontal one to list the tags).

For the tags, you might want to take a look at Material Design ["chips"](https://material.io/design/components/chips.html), but honestly that's the part of this mockup that would have me the most concerned. You can make it look however you want, but I'm not sure what your designer means there exactly. Is that a static list of filtering options? Is that on a new page? In a dialog?

EDIT: And as for the top bar, check out the standard [App Bar](https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/) before reinventing the wheel there.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, the tag section is like the one we get in stackoverflow itlself while asking questions. We tag something to sort among ocean of data, similarly I want to add that tags section as a filter section. I don't want to add complex filtering system as the need is a "basic app" so I made it as simple as it can be. 

And about the cards, I want to keep adding new products and show dynamic data there, like we see 10 blog posts in a single blog post, just like that, then how would I edit every single edit as a individual entity? I have to define some predefined layout for it.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code which will create skeleton for your UI requirement. You can modify it according to your need.

Your Activity/Fragment xml will look like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup
        android:id="@+id/entry_chip_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cl_parent">

    </com.google.android.material.chip.ChipGroup>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/entry_chip_group"

        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You Adapter xml for RecyclerView  will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_product"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Product Name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/iv_product"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Product Information"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_more_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="More info"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_info" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_data"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Data"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_more_info" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_tags"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Tags"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/tv_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_data" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

You should use `Chips` for your **Filter tag**. You can add them dynamically to your `chip group`. Below is the link for reference.

[How to use Android Chips](https://www.truiton.com/2018/10/android-chips-example-material-design/)

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely go with [Recyclerview](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html) or [this tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) for your products(images and the product description...) and [FrameLayout](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_frame_layout.htm) for the top that includes logo and stuff and finally a regular RelativeLayout for the tags.